# Update value in custom list that exists on SPHost for the SharePoint Provider hosted App

Tags: splistitem, jsom, provider-hosted-app

I have a `Provider Hosted App` from where I need to update a list item in the `SPHost` i.e the site where I have added this App.

I have written my code in the JavaScript file but when I try executing it, I get the following error in console:

> MicrosoftAjax.js:5 Refused to get unsafe header "SPRequestGuid"

Please provide insights on how can I go ahead with this.